# Remove the last value after a comma in nvarchar SQL

Tags: sql-server, string

I have a column (Col1) with `nvarchar(50)` values like this: '17031021__,0,0.1,1'. I want to use this value to update another column(Col2), but remove the last number after the last comma (ex: '17031021__,0,0.1'). I think I need something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
Col1 nvarchar(50),
Col2 nvarchar(50)
);
UPDATE table1
SET Col1 =  '17031021__,0,0.1,1'
Select reverse(stuff(reverse(Col1), 1, 1, '')) As Col2
```

This is not quite right. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: You should include a larger set of starting sample data.  Knowing this data might be critical to answering your question.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Will amend to include data.

Comment: Ideally you should be fixing your design and *not* be storing delimited data in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the aforementioned solutions seemed like overkill, so I was able to find an easier solution that worked. Here is what I used generically:

```
 UPDATE [dbo].[table1]
 SET [Col2] = left (Col1, len(Col1) - charindex(',', reverse(Col1) + ','))
```

Very similar to the second solution above but with the `','` added at the end. This produced the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the following will give you a head-start.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('17031021__,0,0.1,1');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT *
    , LEFT(tokens, pos) AS result
FROM @tbl 
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEN(tokens) - CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(tokens))) AS t(pos);
```

And after you feel comfortable:

```
UPDATE @tbl
SET tokens = LEFT(tokens, LEN(tokens) - CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(tokens)));

-- test
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```